# How do i calculate input value on change and also it should show the default value result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.form-group').on('change', '.prc', function() {
  let totalSum = 0;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function() {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {

      totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }

  });
  $('#result').html(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="range" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
```

This script only calculating data after change the input field but how do I also calculate the default value I have added on any field even If I don't add any value then it should show result 0,

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This script only calculating data after change the input field but **how
> do I also calculate the default**

Just do 2 steps like below:

1. Move the logic into `Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult()` method.
2. Call it by default (Let's say on `payload` or `document.ready`) and pass it as callback function `on change` event listener.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult(); // Do it to calculate the default.
   });

   $('.form-group').on('change','.prc', Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult);
   ```

```js
Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult();

$('.form-group').on('change','.prc', Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult);

function Calculate_Then_AssignValueToResult(){
    let totalSum = 0;
    $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
        let inputVal = $(this).val();
        if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
        }
    });
    
    $('#result').html(totalSum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="range" class="form-control prc" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate on initial load, you just needed **trigger**...

```js
$('.form-group').on('change', '.prc', function() {
  let totalSum = 0;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function() {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {

      totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }

  });
  $('#result').html(totalSum);
});

$('.prc').trigger("change"); //just added trigger in your code for initial
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="range" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
```